# What does Srinivasa Ramanujan's wife say before cutting his hair?

Tags: the-man-who-knew-infinity

In [*The Man Who Knew Infinity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Knew_Infinity#Reception), a biopic about the mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan, there's a scene at the 20 minute 30 second mark where Ramanujan (Dev Patel) is about to have his hair cut by his wife, Janaki (Devika Bhise). Just before cutting it, she utters something. Given the religious context of the scene I'm assuming this is some sort of Hindu incantation in Hindi, or possibly Sanskrit, which I believe is Hinduism's liturgical language.

What exactly does Ramanujan's wife say before cutting his hair, and how is her pronunciation of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like Om Narayanaya - in this case used almost as a "god forgive us".

Now the *difficult* thing to if its authentic is accents vary a lot - My mom and dad are *roughly* around that area, *but* there's also caste variations, and subcaste variations. Iyangars (Vaishavite brahmins) as Ramanujan was have their own quirks as well.

I'd say the pronounciation isn't something I'd recognise outright as 'correct' -while its two words, there's some nuance there that a native speaker would catch.

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia page: [Om Namo Narayanaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Namo_Narayanaya). It sounds like she says "ha" instead of "ya" as the last syllable for some reason, but otherwise it sounds right to me. (Also, it is indeed Sanskrit.)